# GoogleMaps.LocationServices NuGet package says namespace could not be found

Tags: android, visual-studio, google-maps, xamarin, nuget

I am creating an android application using Xamarin on Visual Studio 2017. I am trying to use the NuGet package GoogleMaps.LocationServices using this guide (http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/find-latitude-and-longitude-using-c-sharp1). I have installed the package fine 
[image]
But when I try to use the package on my code like the guide I following does I just get an error saying it can't find the namespace:
[image]
This means that I cannot create a GoogleLocationService() object which is what I need to do to create a Google Maps pin point using a list of location addresses.

Anyone got any idea why I'd be getting this error? Unsure if I just need to use a different namespace now as this guide was from 2013.

Answer (score 2):

The GoogleMaps.LocationServices 1.2.1 NuGet package contains an assembly for .NET 4.0 and no other target frameworks. So it does not support Android projects. NuGet will not add a reference to the GoogleMaps.Gelocation assembly since it is in the lib/net40 directory so it not considered compatible.

Instead I would take a look at the [Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Location/60.1142.0-rc1) NuGet package.

Looking at the content of the NuGet package it has a content file `GoogleMaps.LocationServices.readme.txt` which seems to be why you can install it into a Android project. This `GoogleMaps.LocationServices.readme.txt` file is added to your project.

Ideally the NuGet package should have a `readme.txt` file in the root of the NuGet package and not add a file to the project. Such a readme.txt file would be automatically opened on installation by Visual Studio without the need to add anything to the project. Removing the content file would also prevent the NuGet package from being installed into an Android project, or any other unsupported project type.

The older GoogleMaps.LocationsServices 0.9.0 can be installed into an Android project but that seems to be because the NuGet package is not packaged correctly. The GoogleMaps.Gelocation assembly in this version of the NuGet package is in the lib directory and does not indicate any target framework so it is allowed in all project types, which does not seem to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to trace what a new signature of the methods are in 2017, but from my brief look if you change the version on a package to 
`0.9.0` and use namespace

```
using GoogleMaps.Geolocation;
```

The example should work.